# WeakReference to Action target is always alive for anonymous actions

Tags: c#, delegates, garbage-collection, action, weak-references

I'm trying my hands on an event aggregator and I'm storing actions in a wrapper class where I store the actual action method as a `Delegate`, and the class the action method is in as a `WeakReference`.

When I want to call the event handlers I first check if the WeakReference.IsAlive is true. If it is then I call it, otherwise I remove it from the collection because it means the object to which it belongs has been nulled/garbage collected.

However, when I create an anonymous action and add that to my event aggregator it is always alive, even if I null the parent class (and forcebly run the Garbage Collector).

How can I get IsAlive on the anonymous method to be set to FALSE?

```
void AddHandler<TEvent>(Action<TEvent> callback) {
    InternalHandler handler = new InternalHandler(callback);
    // Store the handler somewhere to use the callback later, if it still alive
}

class InternalHandler {
    WeakReference _reference;
    Delegate _method;

    public InternalHandler(Delegate handler) {
        _reference = new WeakReference(handler.Target);

        Type messageType = handler.Method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        Type delegateType = typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(handler.Target.GetType(), messageType);

        _method = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, handler.Method);
    }

    bool IsAlive => _reference != null && _reference.IsAlive;

    bool Invoke(object data) {
        if (!IsAlive) return false;

        if (_reference.Target != null) _method.DynamicInvoke(_reference.Target, data);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And in the test application

```
TempObject t = new TempObject();

// Some time later
t = null;
GC.Collect();

class TempObject {

    public TempObject() {
        myHandler.AddHandler<SomeObject>(o => {
            // Some code with a breakpoint
        });
    }
}
```

After having called `GC.Collect()` and I send out a new event, the breakpoint in the anonymous method in `t` is still called!

How can I get a proper `WeakReference` to an anonymous method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow I *assume* that you don't reference any instance variables (so, don't use "this") in your anonymous `TempObject` handler, because such assumption leads to observed behavior.

To fully understand the reason, the easiest method is to look up the code which is generated by C# compiler for anonymous method you mentioned. The code is rather unreadable because of the names of classes and variables used, but here is a bit prettified version:

```
class TempObject {
    public TempObject(Handlers handlers) {
        handlers.AddHandler<object>(GeneratedClass._staticAction ?? (GeneratedClass._staticAction = GeneratedClass._staticField.Handler));
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Serializable]
    private sealed class GeneratedClass {
        public static readonly TempObject.GeneratedClass _staticField;
        public static Action<object> _staticAction;

        static GeneratedClass() {
            TempObject.GeneratedClass._staticField = new TempObject.GeneratedClass();
        }

        public GeneratedClass() {

        }

        internal void Handler(object o) {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }
    }
}
```

You see here that compiler generated new class (named `GeneratedClass` here), which has one **static** field with the reference to an instance of this class, and also another static field where reference to your anonymous handler is cached. So, your anonymous delegate is really instance method (named Handler) of an instance of class `GeneratedClass`, which instance is stored in **static** field.

At this point you should already realize why you observe such behavior. Your reference is

```
 _reference = new WeakReference(handler.Target);
```

And handler.Target in this case references to the static field which is never set to null, so is never garbage collected.

Another way to intuitively understand it is that you never use anything related to an **instance** of `TempObject` in your anonymous handler, and so your anonymous method is basically a reference to static method (conceptually), not to an instance method. So it actually does not have any relation to `TempObject` instances and it's lifetime is not related to lifetime of `TempObjects`. So basically it's the same as:

```
class TempObject {
    public TempObject(Handlers handlers) {
        handlers.AddHandler<object>(Handler);
    }

    private static void Handler(object arg) {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

And of course it's not surprising that your method won't work for static methods as expected (actually for static method, handler.Target will be null, so your code will fail I suppose).

Now let's change this a bit:

```
class TempObject {

    public TempObject(Handlers handlers) {
        handlers.AddHandler<object>(o => {
            Console.WriteLine(o + this.Name);
        });
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This time your handler **does** reference "this" and so it is related to an instance of `TempObject` class. Compiler will generate different code for this sitatation which I won't show here, but the net result will be that in this case your `WeakReference` will not be alive when TempObject is garbage collected, so will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply :) I did notice that if I added a reference to "this" that it got GC'ed when TempObject got GC'ed. However, I have some usecases where I wouldn't reference "this", which means that the static GeneratedClass will be created. Is there no way to remove this static reference when TempObject is GC'ed? And if there is, how can I then make sure that `_reference.Target != null` even if it is static? In other words, how can I create a work-around for this issue without needing to reference "this"?

Comment: No there is no way to remove it, because it's readonly (even if you somehow managed to use reflection). Same story with passing regular static methods - their Target is null and you cannot do anything with that. I suggest you to allow passing "owner" object explicitly: AddHandler(owner, (0) => ....). When present - use that for your weak reference. If you make that optional, it's still possible to misuse your api, so you might consider making it required.

Comment: I think I understand now. Out of curiosity, will this happen to all anonymous methods, or only the ones where my event handler is keeping a reference? If this happens regardless of my event handler, won't this be a sort of a memory leak in C#.Net?

Comment: Yes that happens regardless of your handler. But it's about the same as introducing your own static method (remember, when you reference something from outer scope, like "this", it works differently and target object is garbage collected). So compiler introduces couple of static variables where it caches your delegate reference, only once (not every time, so I mean not every time you create TempObject for example), so I can hardly name that memory leak. It's a bit more expensive than static method, but not too much.